# how to make read() in thread block on a pipe's file descriptor?

Tags: c, pthreads, pipe, file-descriptor

I'm experimenting on how to communicate between a thread and the main function in C
There is a behavior that I don't understand in the following code :

```
#include <pthread.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void* output(void* pipe1);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t   tid0;
    int         pipe1[2];
    char        buffer[200];

// Creating the pipe
    pipe(pipe1);
// Creating the thread and passing the pipe as argument
    pthread_create(&tid0, NULL, output, &pipe1);
// Input from user
    scanf("%s", buffer);
// Writing to the pipe
    write(pipe1[1], buffer, strlen(buffer));
    return 0;
}

void* output(void* pipe1) {
     char buffer[200];

// Reading the pipe and print the buffer
     read(((int*)pipe1)[0], buffer, strlen(buffer));
     printf("thread say: %s\n", buffer);
     pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Why the read function doesn't block on the pipe's file descriptor ?

Maybe I should close the end of the pipe but since they share the same memory space, the error "bad file descriptor" is returned when I will call read or write.

Maybe you can guide me to other methods if pipe is really a bad solution (with an example it will be amazing ! :) )

Many thanks !

EDIT: SOLUTION

Many thank for your answer here is the code that have the expected behavior

```
#include <pthread.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* output(void* pipe1);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t   tid0;
    int         pipe1[2];
    char        buffer[200];

// Creating the pipe
    pipe(pipe1);
// Creating the thread and passing the pipe as argument
    pthread_create(&tid0, NULL, output, &pipe1);

// Input from user
    scanf("%s", buffer);
// Writing to the pipe
    if (write(pipe1[1], buffer, strlen(buffer)) < 0) {
        perror("write");
        exit(1);
    }
    // join so the main "wait" for the thread
    pthread_join(tid0, NULL);
    return 0;
}


void* output(void* pipe1) {
    char        buffer[200];
    int         nread;

// Reading the pipe and print the buffer
    nread = read(((int*)pipe1)[0], buffer, sizeof buffer - 1);
    if (nread < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR\n");
        perror("read");
        exit(1);
    }
    buffer[nread] = '\0';
    fprintf(stderr, "thread say: %s\n", buffer);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Using more than one thread is called multithreading, did you mix up that term somehow? Also, "communicate between thread", do you really mean singular? That said, you can use pipes for communication between threads, though a message queue is probably the better tool.

Comment: how yes thanks I will try to edit my post to make it more clear, thank you for your comment

Comment: `main` and functions called from it are not special. It's the first thread that is started, but it is a thread like all others. Just to shatter another misconception. ;)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt There is one thing special about `main()`, though:  return from it and your process ends.  That's likely part of the problem here - `main()` starts a child thread, then doesn't wait for it to finish before returning and ending the entire process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char buffer[200];
read(((int*)pipe1)[0], buffer, strlen(buffer));
```

You are calling `strlen` on an uninitialized buffer.  This is allowed to crash your program.  Instead, you got lucky, and all it did was tell `read` to read zero bytes, so `read` returned without doing anything.

What you actually want is

```
ssize_t nread = read(((int *)pipe1)[0], buffer, sizeof buffer - 1);
if (nread < 0) {
    perror("read");
    return 0;
}
buffer[nread] = '\0';
```

What `read` wants to be told is how much *space* you are giving it to read into, not the length of any string that may or may not already be in that space.  That's `sizeof buffer`, minus one so we always have space to add a string terminator.

It's correct to use `strlen` when *writing*, because you only want to write the actual string, not any junk that might be beyond the end of the string; but then `write` doesn't write the string terminator to the pipe, so `read` doesn't *read* one, so you have to add it by hand.  And, of course, always check for errors.

Also, keep in mind that the threads run *simultaneously*.  Even after fixing this bug, the `write` may already have happened by the time the reader-thread calls `read`, and if it hasn't, it probably will happen very soon.  If you want to observe the reader-thread actually blocking in `read` you need to delay before calling `write`.

Comment: Oh thank you so much I didn't realize that, I should have read the man more carefully ! I will test this on my code and update the post if I succeed.

Comment: Ok after some other adjustment in my code It work as expected, thank you very much ! :)